# Displaying information using ggvis

Tags: r, ggvis

I am working on a shiny app using ggvis graphs. I am trying to have the information display once the mouse moves over a point on the graph. If I using `layer_points`, the data about the specific point is shown correctly. However, if I use `layer_bars`, then it shows the values are `NULL` even though the dataset has not been changed.

```
dfL %>% ggvis(x = ~time, y = ~amount) %>% layer_points() 
%>% add_tooltip(all_values, "hover") %>% bind_shiny("AnPlot", "AnPlot_ui")
```

^information displays correctly.

```
dfL %>% ggvis(x = ~time, y = ~amount) %>% layer_bars(width=1, fill:= "white") 
%>% add_tooltip(all_values, "hover") %>% bind_shiny("AnPlot", "AnPlot_ui")
```

^Receive NULL for values.

Here is the code for `all_values`.

```
all_values <- function(x) {
  if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  paste0("Amount: ", format(x$amount, digits=4), 
  " Present Value: ", format(x$pv, digits=4), collapse = "<br />")
}
```

The data frame `dfL` has three columns: time, pv, and amount. I tried to only provide relevant code here, but if other portions are necessary, I will edit the post and include it.

I cannot figure out why it would return the correct values when the graph is a scatterplot, but be unable to return the values when it is a bar graph.

Thanks for any insight you can provide!

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a tricky problem to deal with because unfortunately not all types of `layer`s play as nicely with `add_tooltip` as `layer_points` does. I'm not 100% clear on all the implementation details of many `ggvis` functions, but I will at least walk you through my understanding of it so you can see how I arrived at my solution. I'm going to use the `cars` data set (which should be available in your session by default) to demonstrate, but you will only have to make some minor adjustments to apply the methodology to your own data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
##
my_data <- cars %>% 
  group_by(speed) %>% 
  summarize(avg_dist = mean(dist))
##
R> my_data
Source: local data frame [19 x 2]

   speed avg_dist
1      4  6.00000
2      7 13.00000
3      8 16.00000
4      9 10.00000
5     10 26.00000
6     11 22.50000
7     12 21.50000
8     13 35.00000
9     14 50.50000
10    15 33.33333
11    16 36.00000
12    17 40.66667
13    18 64.50000
14    19 50.00000
15    20 50.40000
16    22 66.00000
17    23 54.00000
18    24 93.75000
19    25 85.00000
```

I'm also going to define a couple of visualizations using this grouped data - `bar_obj` (the bar plot) and `point_obj` (the scatter plot); and a function `vis_names` which will just print out of the names of the data object that gets passed to `add_tooltip`.

```
bar_obj <- my_data %>% 
  ggvis(x = ~speed, y = ~avg_dist) %>%
  layer_bars()
##
point_obj <- my_data %>% 
  ggvis(x = ~speed, y = ~avg_dist) %>%
  layer_points()
##
vis_names <- function(x) {
  if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  paste0(names(x),collapse="<br />")
}
```

Printing out the names from inside of `add_tooltip` is a good way to figure out exactly what data is being passed around. For `point_obj`, we have:

```
point_obj %>% add_tooltip(vis_names,"hover")
```

[image]

which are the column names of my input data. On the other hand, doing this for `bar_obj` gives us:

```
bar_obj %>% add_tooltip(vis_names,"hover")
```

[image]

which are definitely not column names in `my_data`. If we define another function,

```
bar_info <- function(x) {
  if(is.null(x)) return(NULL) 

  paste(
    names(x)[1],
    x[1,1],
    names(x)[2],
    x[1,2],
    names(x)[3],
    x[1,3],
    names(x)[4],
    x[1,4],
    sep=" : ",
    collapse="<br />")
}
```

we can get a little more detail:

```
bar_obj %>% add_tooltip(bar_info,"hover")
```

[image]

So the `xmin_` and `xmax_` are apparently the x-coordinates of the given bar we are hovering over, while `stack_upr_` and `stack_lwr_` are the respective y-coordinates. From here, we just need a way to translate the bar coordinates back to the original input data, `my_data`.

In `ggplot2` there is a neat function I often use called `ggplot_build`. When you call this function on a `ggplot` object it creates the plot (just as printing would normally do), but also returns very detailed information about everything that went into constructing the plot - major axis ranges, minor axis ranges, etc... This is really useful when you need to find out very precise information about your graph. I suspected that `ggvis` would have something similar to `ggplot_build`, and looking through the vignette I found the function `get_data`. Calling this on a `ggvis` object returns a list of `data.frame`s, where the first element is the original `data.frame` (`my_data`), and the fourth element is a `data.frame` that contains, among other things, the four columns shown in the bar plot above - `xmin_`, `xmax_`, `stack_upr_`, and `stack_lwr_`.

From here, I'll define a final function that will be passed to `add_tooltip` for use with `bar_obj`:

```
tooltip_bars <- function(x) {
  if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)

  bar_obj <- get("bar_obj",.GlobalEnv)

  input_data <- get_data(bar_obj)[[1]]
  bar_data <- get_data(bar_obj)[[4]]
  xmin_col <- bar_data[,3]

  row_idx <- which.min(abs(x[1,1]-xmin_col))

  paste0(
    paste0(names(input_data)[1],
           ": ",
           format(input_data[row_idx,1],4)), 
    paste0(names(input_data)[2],
           ": ",
           format(input_data[row_idx,2],4)), 
    collapse = "<br />")
}
```

There's a lot going on in here - it's certainly not as concise as the `all_values` tooltip function, but it gets the job done. This line

```
bar_obj <- get("bar_obj",.GlobalEnv)
```

grabs a copy of the `ggvis` object we are actually plotting from the global environment and pulls it into the scope of our tooltip sub-function. The next two lines,

```
input_data <- get_data(bar_obj)[[1]]
bar_data <- get_data(bar_obj)[[4]]
```

store our input data set (equivalent to `my_data`) and the bar coordinates used in the plot, i.e. what we can access through the variable `x`. `xmin_col` is the column of values defining the left-hand-side x-coordinates of the bars. By comparing this to the `xmin_` value contained in `x`, we can figure out what row of data is being plotted, i.e.

```
row_idx <- which.min(abs(x[1,1]-xmin_col))
```

For this example there may be an easier way of comparing our value `x[1,1]` to the column `xmin_` to determine the row of data that is currently being hovered over. I used the `which.min(...)` approach above because I think it would be more robust in cases where, for example, `xmin_` values are not exactly some integer + 0.5, as they are in this situation. Trying to test for exact equality between floating point number can sometimes be problematic.

Anyhow, we can use the `row_idx` we created to extract the row of our original data represented by the bar we are hovering over (i.e. what `x` contains), which is done in the `paste0(...)` part. The result looks like this:

```
bar_obj %>% add_tooltip(tooltip_bars,"hover")
```

[image]

For some reason the labels were not formatting correctly; although this shouldn't have anything to do with the general approach I used.

So getting back to your original question about why the `NULL` values were being displayed, the short answer is that the data object passed to `add_tooltip` in a `layer_points` visualization is not the same as what is passed to it in a `layer_bars` visualization, so calling `x$amount` and `x$pv` will return `NULL`, since these columns were not present in `x`.

And just to clarify, to apply this code to your own data make sure that you create a base `ggvis` object like I did with `bar_obj`, and substitute its name where I used `"bar_obj"` in the `get("bar_obj",.GlobalEnv)` line of the `tooltip_bars` function.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. However, I am having some problems implementing it. I created a base `ggvis` object: `layer_bars(x = ~time, y = ~pv, fill := "#B0B0B0")`. Then I updated `tooltip_bars`: `tooltip_bars <- function(x) { ...  
  bar_obj <- get("levelAn_obj",.GlobalEnv)...`. Lastly, I graph it: `levelAn_obj %>% add_tooltip(tooltip_bars,"hover") %>% bind_shiny("AnPlot", "AnPlot_ui")`. When I run the app, the graph displays but I receive this error `Warning: Unhandled error in observer: object 'levelAn_obj' not found` when I hover. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Correction, I see I did not completely copy the object in the above comment. The `ggvis` object is `levelAn_obj <- dfL %>% ggvis(x =~time, y = ~amount)  %>% layer_bars() %>% layer_bars(x = ~time, y = ~pv, fill := "#B0B0B0")`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. I resolved it by explicitly filtering the data set to the row that the hover belongs to, like:

```
  my_tooltip <- function(x) {
    # do some checks   
    if (is.null(x)) return(NULL)
    if (is.null(x$bin)) return(NULL)
    # select the data for the bar you're hovered over
    all_data <- my.data()
    this_data <- all_data[all_data$bin == x$bin, ]
    paste0("<b>", this_data$bin, ": ", "</b><br>", format(this_data$value))
  }
```

where the incoming data have been defined in a reactive function, e.g.

```
my_data <- reactive({
  df <- df.all  # simplest example
  df <- df.all[df.all$group==input$selected_group,]  # example using user input
})
```

given `names(df.all)` are `"group" "bin" "value"`.

Then I called the tooltip function within the reactive `vis` function:

```
  vis <- reactive({ 
    plot.data %>%
      ggvis(x=~bin, y=~value, key := ~bin) %>%  # key on `bin` here
      layer_bars(width=1, fill=~group) %>% 
      add_tooltip(my_tooltip, "hover")
  })
  vis %>% bind_shiny("my_plot")  # bind with UI name
```

It's not clear from the [documentation](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/ggvis/man/add_tooltip.html) that you need to key on `bin` in my example since it's one of the pieces of data in the plot. However, I found that the tooltip wouldn't appear without that parameter explicitly set.